# Which PHP 5.3 features and extensions are not compatible with stream wrappers?

Tags: php, php-5.3

I am in the process of migrating a lot of files in a large PHP application from local to remote storage. File operations are being transitioned using PHP stream wrappers as an intermediate solution so that we can easily change calls such as `fopen('/local/file/path')` to `fopen('scheme://remote/file/path')`.

So far I've come across only one feature which is broken by this, which is the GD image library (its file write methods such as imagejpeg, imagegif and imagepng will not write to file streams).

In addition, PHP security options deny `include()` and `require()` calls on URLs.

I've tried looking for a list of known incompatibilities but can't find one.

I already have several workarounds available, so I'm covered there, and we'll perform extensive testing, but I would like to know in advance of any pain points if someone's been through the same process before.

Specifically, we are using PHP 5.3.6 on Debian Squeeze.

Comment: These are available in the php.net book

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reading this:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.streamwrapper.php

A lot of your answers will be found there.

Comment: Sorry, but the answers aren't there, and I've been over that section of the PHP manual many times when actually implementing the wrapper code. That page only lists _how_ to implement stream wrappers, not which features are incompatible with them (specifically, there's no mention of the features I highlighted in my original question).